# Facebook review required for iOS apps that have the SDK just for app install ads?

Tags: ios, facebook, sdk, facebook-ads-api

I have an app in the Appstore for a few months now. To use App Install optimized Facebook ads, I decided to integrate The Facebook SDK. But apart from running Ad Campaigns on Facebook, I am *not* using any of the functionalities offered by the Facebook SDK. i.e. I am not using Facebook login and the services used with Facebook Login.

I noticed that the Facebook app is in Sandbox Mode and I need to set it to Public to use Facebook App Install advertising. I can set it to public right away, which is good.

But there is also a Facebook review submission button on the same page and there is a not-so-clear statement on the page saying Facebook needs to review "some" of the integrations before going live.

If I am using the SDK just for Facebook Ads with my "iOS App", do I still need to have my app reviewed by Facebook?

Cheers,

Taner

Comment: You would have to ask facebook.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are not requesting to use any of the permissions, you do not need to have your app reviewed.

The only thing you need to do the enable it to be used for advertising is to set it to be Public. This will not really do anything in your case.